# spring integration tcp socket is being closed immediately

Tags: spring, sockets, tcp, integration

I am new to Spring integration and tcp ip module, I need some help.

I am building a simple project, where I should read data from a port , an external source (embedded system) pushes some raw data on a specified port address (in this example port is 4321)

the data sample is something like this: 
`$1,101,16,10,14,01,32,05,343N,0987E,000.0,301,0,A#$1,101,16,10,14,01,32,05,343N,0987E,000.0,301,0,A#`

the device pushes data whenever it has, it sends even more than 600 chars at a time,

I want to access the data in portService class and test method, I have a delimiter `#`, since every message ends with `#`, I dont have control on client data (I cannot change the data format or I cant append `\r\n` to it)

tcp client server config :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

<bean id="customSerializer" class="com.gerrydevstory.service.CustomSerializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverConnectionFactory" 
    type="server" 
    host="localhost" 
    port="4321" 
    single-use="false"
    so-timeout="100000"
    using-nio="true"
    serializer="customSerializer"
    deserializer="customSerializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
    connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory" request-channel="loop" />

<int:channel id="loop" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="loop"
    ref="portService" method="test">
</int:service-activator>
```

CustomSerializer :

```
public class CustomSerializer extends ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer {

    public CustomSerializer() {
        super((byte) 0x03);
        System.out.println("In Custom Serializer...");
    }
}
```

PortService :

```
@Component
public class PortService {

    public String test(final String input) {
        System.out.println("PortService :" + input);
        if ("FAIL".equals(input)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failure Demonstration");
        }
        return input + ":echo";
    }
}
```

I enabled the logging Trace:

The control is going to CustomSerializer but not PortService, any help would be highly appreciated.

> TRACE: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': TcpConnectionOpenEvent [source=org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection@13c2d58], [factory=serverConnectionFactory, connectionId=xxx.xxxx.xx.xx:9226:4321:e63ea33e-a9e7-416a-bfd6-dc53d5de00c6] **OPENED**
>
> TRACE: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection@13c2d58], [factory=serverConnectionFactory, connectionId=xxx.xxxx.xx.xx:9226:4321:e63ea33e-a9e7-416a-bfd6-dc53d5de00c6] **CLOSED**
>
> TRACE: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent [source=com.gerrydevstory.service.CustomSerializer@4833ff0b, cause=java.io.IOException: Socket closed during message assembly]

When I tried to test the samething with the following code snippent it worked :

```
server = new ServerSocket(port);
int index = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Waiting for client request");
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    InputStream ois = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    ois.read(buf);
    System.out.write(buf);

    System.out.println("Message Received: " + buf);
    socket.close();
    if (index++ > 5) {
        break;
    }
}
server.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the data is being pushed from an embedded system, stream is in raw format (byte array)

ByteArrayRawSerializer can handle this use case.

I added the following code snippet config file :

```
<bean id="byteArrayRawSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayRawSerializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverConnectionFactory" 
    type="server" 
    host="localhost" 
    port="4321" 
    single-use="false"
    using-nio="false"
    so-timeout="300000"
    serializer="byteArrayRawSerializer"
    deserializer="byteArrayRawSerializer"
    />
```

solved the problem.

Thanks.